# solve linear congruence ax + by = c

Tags: number-theory

Hi I'm reading Underwood Dudleys' Elementary Number theory 2nd edition.

I find this proof based book very difficult as I'm an engineer and have learnt maths without proofs.

Anyway on page 37 (see picture below) I cannot follow why 16y congruent 35 (mod 9) is equivalent to 7y congruent 35 (mod 9). I can see that 16 - 9 is 7 but why that would work I don't know.

So if somebody could explain that'd be great.

[image]

Comment: This is because, as you've seen it, $16\equiv 7\mod 9$, and we can use congruences as we use equalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $a\equiv b \bmod 9$ means $9\mid a-b$, by definition. So $16y\equiv 35 \bmod 9$ means
$$
9\mid 16y-35=9y+7y-35
$$
Since $9$ divides $9y$, this implies $9\mid 7y-35$, i.e., $7y\equiv 35\bmod 9$.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to make things more concrete.  Over here in the U.S., we have $\$5$ bills, as you may know, and also we have these $\$2$ bills, which few people see anymore, but which some of us have inexplicably socked away.

At any rate, suppose we have $\$47$ in some mixture of $x\text{ }\$5$ bills and $y\text{ }\$2$ bills, so we know

$$
5x+2y = 47
$$

What can we say about this?  We can say that whatever money we have in $\$5$ bills, it leaves the same remainder as $47$ does, when you divide it by $2$ (because no amount of $\$2$ bills can change the remainder when you divide by $2$).  Symbolically, this is

$$
5x \equiv 47 \pmod{2}
$$

Further, subtracting $4x$ from the left hand side (if you were somehow able to turn all those $\$5$ bills into $\$1$ bills) would not affect the equivalence, because $4$ is divisible by $2$, so

$$
x \equiv 47 \pmod{2}
$$

Note that it is also true that whatever money we have in $\$2$ bills, it leaves the same remainder as $47$ does, when you divide it by $5$ (because no amount of $\$5$ bills can change the remainder when you divide by $5$):

$$
2y \equiv 47 \pmod{5}
$$